# How to refresh a component after already visiting it?

Tags: reactjs

Working on a project and when changing routes, coming back to one after already visiting it doesnt display new changes/additions. For example, if i route to my "Offers" route, it will display my offers on current items for rent. If i then leave that route and go and place another offer on an item, routing back to "Offers" will reveal no changes unless I refresh the page. I populate the state in componentdidmount() but have also tried other ways where im not using componentdidmount() to populate it. What options do I have here? I can post the component if needed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried so far so we can reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Going back to a route which was already visited in the same `BrowserRouter` context, will not MOUNT the component again. It would only cause the router to perform a `pop` action, which causes the browser to pop the latest DOM generated for that route to pop from the router context. So what you would have to do, is to check if the user has pressed back button in his/her browser. To do so, you can check `this.props.history.action === 'POP'` in `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle. Something like this:

```
class Offers extends Component {
    constuctor (props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            offers: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        this.fetchOffersAndStoreThemInState();
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps () {
        if (this.props.history.action === 'POP') {
            this.fetchOffersAndStoreThemInState();
        }
    }
}
```

And don't forget to wrap your component with `withRouter` to have access to the `history` object.

Comment: Would this only work using the back button to get to the original component? Or also when I redirect to the component?

Comment: You are using `componentDidMount` lifecycle to initialize your data when the user is visiting the route for the first time.  The `if` within `componentWillReceiveProps` is used to handle the logic for the next visits.

Comment: Awesome, but im confused when you say wrap my component in withrouter(), you mean the entire class? (such as starting from where "export default class Offers..." is?)

Comment: `const OffersWithRouter = withRouter(Offers)`
and in the begining of your file: `import { withRouter } from 'react-router'`

Comment: Ah gotcha, but now getting this error "export 'default' (imported as 'withRouter') was not found in 'react-router'. Any ideas? Couldn't really find what I was looking for online. Thanks

Comment: Have you put curly braces before and after `withRouter`?!

Comment: Yikes, yeah that was this issue @Masious, oops. Having some issue getting it to do what I want but ill play around with it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. Upvoting and accepting my answer would be nice. :)

Comment: Not able to because my rep isn't high enough? Says it was recorded though. Also, when im console logging the props history, its giving me a REPLACE instead of POP when I route back to Offers? Guess i should just use === "REPLACE" ?

Comment: A better solution would be `['REPLACE', 'POP'].includes(this.props.history.action)` to check both!

Comment: Good idea, however seems as if the componentWillReceiveProps() isnt getting called or the if statement isn't triggering.